# Wifi Diagnostics get WiFi performance

Tags: wifi

Is there any way to get the wifi performance using the Wifi Diagnostics?

I have a 802.11n network running on Apple TimeMachine.

The Wifi Diagnostics created diagnostics report but I don't know which log file would have this information?

Can someone point me to the right file?

Comment: I found this http://www.macworld.com/article/1140684/check_wifi_speeds.html which states that older Airport Utility had a Logs/Statistics option. Was this moved to some other application?

Answer (score 1):

When the Wi-Fi diagnostics tool finishes, the logs get saved to your desktop.

If that didn't happen or was deleted, you will have to find them from a backup or re-run the tool.

[image]

Depending on what performance you are monitoring, I would start with the two files to get a summary of the signal and noise of your Wi-Fi recording session:

- **link-events.log**:
- **link-info.log**:

Comment: I have the logs but which log file would have the performance numbers?