# wifi.log disappeared?

Tags: macos, airport, logs, console

I had some trouble with my wifi connection so I figured, I could switch on logging for airport via

`sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport debug +AllUserLand +LogFile`

Now as far as I remember, the `+LogFile`should redirect the airport debug log from kernel.log to wifi.log. Checking Console, I notice that there is no wifi.log under /var/log/. On a closer look, I noticed that kernel.log disappeared as well.

After some googling I found [this post](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/283178-kernellog-is-gone-after-1082-update/), in which it says that kernel.log was merged into system.log. Now if that is true, I'm suspecting that the reason I can't locate wifi.log might be that it was perhaps merged with system.log as well. Does anyone have some further info on this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, all the debug info from airport that used to be in `/var/log/wifi.log` is now located in `/var/log/system.log`. Also, the `+LogFile` option has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mountain Lion does log a limited amount of information to

`/private/var/log/wifi.log`

To read that file – and its siblings such as `wifi.log.0.bz2` – use Console.

Included with the operating system is a [diagnostics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24259/8546) app that can enable debug logging. With that level of logging enabled you can then use Console to:

- view all messages
- add a system log query
- and so on.

Also in Stack Exchange:

- [Wifi Diagnostics get WiFi performance](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/76571/8546) (2013-01-02)

Comment: With the latest update, wifi.log appears in Console again. So do a number of other logs that previously disappeared.